# MVC project with data access on a WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I know that sounds strange.
I'm working on an exercise project: A simple money manager.
This is the database diagram:

[image]

I started creating a WCF service that contains all the data access methods.
This is the folder structure:

[image]

Inside the Model folder there are the classes like a MVC project.

And here the Service.svc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using WCFServices.Money.Model;

namespace WCFServices.Money
{
    // NOTA: è possibile utilizzare il comando "Rinomina" del menu "Refactoring" per modificare il nome di classe "Service" nel codice, nel file svc e nel file di configurazione contemporaneamente.
    // NOTA: per avviare il client di prova WCF per testare il servizio, selezionare Service.svc o Service.svc.cs in Esplora soluzioni e avviare il debug.
public class Service : IService
{
    MoneyEntities db = new MoneyEntities();

    #region Methods to get items name by Id

    public string GetAccountNameById(long id)
    {
        return db.Accounts.Find(id).Name;
    }

    public string GetBeneficiaryNameById(long id)
    {
        return db.Beneficiaries.Find(id).Name;
    }

    public string GetCategoryNameById(long id)
    {
        return db.Categories.Find(id).Name;
    }

    public string GetProjectNameById(long id)
    {
        return db.Projects.Find(id).Name;
    }

    public string GetSubcategoryNameById(long id)
    {
        return db.Subcategories.Find(id).Name;
    }

    public string GetTimeUnitNameById(long id)
    {
        return db.TimeUnits.Find(id).Name;
    }

    #endregion

    // And so go on...
}
```

}

As you can see it's all very simple.

After I created the MVC project where the service reference has been added.
Now I want to create a Controller for the Transactions table but in the DbContext selector I can't find the DbContext created in the WCF service.

So I created a MoneyEntities.cs also in the MVC project that looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Money.Model
{
    public class MoneyEntities : DbContext
    {
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Account> Accounts { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Beneficiary> Beneficiaries { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Category> Categories { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Interval> Intervals { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Project> Projects { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.TimeUnit> TimeUnits { get; set; }
         public DbSet<ServiceReference.Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So the controller has been created but when I run a view I get a lot of errors...
Have you some suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: So you want WCF access and direct access to the same database? I think i missed something...Shouldn't the WCF service handle all data-related transactions?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the WCF's methods for all database operations. Could be Visual Studio's controllers and views generator the problem? Now I will try to create alone the controller

Comment: Then you don't need `MoneyEntities` in your MVC project. All you need are methods that expose database operations in your WCF service, then call those methods from your MVC application.

Comment: OK, MoneyEntities on MVC project deleted. So how to go on? Have I to write the controller in the WCF service to return the actions that I need to generate the views? I can't access to the MoneyEntities on WCF service from the MVC project.

Comment: Maybe I've an idea... If the 'Index()' action of the controller needs a 'List()' I've to create a method in the WCF service returns this list, right?

Comment: Yes. Everything you need to perform with a client needs to be written on the service.

Comment: OK, thank you. I've another question: what about the Global.asax? I can't add it in the WCF service and in the MVC projects that uses SQL Server I always added something like '            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MVCTest.Model.MoneyEntities>(null)' in the Application_Start().

Comment: May want to consider using the [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Initializers).